# For loop feeding constant values into fsolve in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use matlab's fsolve to solve a system of 4 nonlinear equations. I'm solving the system for each point in a grid of parameters by looping through each point and calling the fsolve function.

My problem is that I need to give some of these parameters as input to fsolve. These inputs should be treated as constants for each separate solving of the system.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Including the code usually increases the chances of people answering your question.

Comment: You can pass whatever variables you need to your cost function by using a function handle like the following: `fhand = @(x)foobar( x, a, b, c, ... );` In the above, `x` will be the vector used by `fsolve` and the other arguments (i.e., `a`, `b`, ...) will be unaltered and passed to the function `foobar` with whatever value they had when the funtion handle was defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just do:

```
result = fsolve(@(x) eqns(a,b,c,d),guess)
```

and in addition make the function eqns() with your equation set.